The Spring-Integration application missing some integration metrics after migration to Azure Spring Apps Service
We have Spring-Integration microservice which uses JMS to handle MQ messages.
The message manager app (another app) makes the rest call to this app to get the stats about successful and failed messages counters. Under the hood it uses /actuator/integrationgraph or /integration endpoints to see those counters.
It works fine on local environment on the same JVM Java 21.0.2 JVM provided by Microsoft and I see those counters.

But after deploy to Azure Spring apps the metrics section responsible for counters is empty

I have feeling that Azure Spring Apps service intercepts the JMX conversation for Azure AppInsight metrics collection and does not forward whole set of metrics.
Please help.
Thank you.
Tried many configuration settings on Azure side, but no luck


have feeling that Azure Spring Apps service intercepts the JMX conversation for Azure AppInsight metrics collection and does not forward whole set of metrics.

Azure Spring Apps service does not directly intercept the JMX conversation for Azure Application Insights metrics collection. Instead, Azure Spring Apps integrates with Azure Monitor Application Insights through the use of the Application Insights Java In-Process Agent.

This agent is configured to collect telemetry, including JMX metrics, from your Java applications running within the Azure Spring Apps environment.

To enable and configure JMX metrics collection, you need to add a "jmxMetrics" section to the applicationinsights.json file, specifying the JMX object names and attributes you want to monitor. This configuration allows Application Insights to collect specific JMX metrics from the application.
applicationinsights.json:
{
  "jmxMetrics": [
    {
      "name": "Successful Messages Count",
      "objectName": "your.integration:name=successfulMessages",
      "attribute": "Count"
    },
    {
      "name": "Failed Messages Count",
      "objectName": "your.integration:name=failedMessages",
      "attribute": "Count"
    }
  ]
}


Please Check whether Spring Integration components are configured to collect metrics. This can be done by enabling statistics and counts on the integration flows and channels.

@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("inputChannel")
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("queueName"))
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public IntegrationManagementConfigurer integrationManagementConfigurer() {
        IntegrationManagementConfigurer configurer = new IntegrationManagementConfigurer();
        configurer.setDefaultCountsEnabled(true);
        configurer.setDefaultStatsEnabled(true);
        return configurer;
    }
}

pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
</dependency>

Deployment status:

Result:
<Graph>
    <contentDescriptor>
        <providerVersion>6.2.5</providerVersion>
        <providerFormatVersion>1.2</providerFormatVersion>
        <provider>spring-integration</provider>
        <name>testapp</name>
    </contentDescriptor>
    <nodes>
        <nodeId>1</nodeId>
        <componentType>channel</componentType>
        <integrationPatternType>message_channel</integrationPatternType>
        <integrationPatternCategory>messaging_channel</integrationPatternCategory>
        <properties/>
        <sendTimers>
            <successfulMessages>
                <count>12</count>
                <mean>0.0</mean>
                <max>0.0</max>
            </successfulMessages>
            <failedMessages>
                <count>7</count>
                <mean>0.0</mean>
                <max>0.0</max>
            </failedMessages>
        </sendTimers>
        <name>inputChannel</name>
        <observed>false</observed>
    </nodes>
</Graph>


Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/20238030/suresh-chikkam!
But I am having problem with the code provided:
.....
configurer.setDefaultCountsEnabled(true);
configurer.setDefaultStatsEnabled(true);
return configurer;
.....
It does not compile. Curious, what Spring boot version you are using? I am on 3.2.5.

I addition, I just simply want to see the same result when I call /integration endpoint locally and in Azure. I did not want AppInsight to include metrics by modifying applicationinsights.json. But thank you  https://stackoverflow.com/users/20238030/suresh-chikkam.

Here I'm using spring Boot 3.2.6 version and I use app insights for tracing nothing more than that... there was no problem if or if not app sights enable.

Microsoft folks were able to reproduce the issue I am experiencing. They are working on it.
